# How to capture recursively delimited strings

Tags: python, regex

I have the following JSON string:

`{"main":{"sem":"segon semestre","year":"2021","AUT":"admin  ","RES":"manel , admin ,lectura ","SUP":"kiloton  ","COR":"   ","fitx":"continguts"}}`

I want to remove whitespace only from the values of: AUT, RES, SUP and COR

```
/"(AUT|COR|RES|SUP)":"((\w*)(\s*)(,*))"/
```

My best approximation, fails to get and clear the RES value\

"\1":"\3"

{"main":{"sem":"segon semestre","year":"2021",**"AUT":"admin"**,"RES":"manel , admin ,lectura ",**"SUP":"kiloton"**,**"COR":""**,"fitx":"continguts"}}\

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Do not modify the JSON string. Convert it to a Python data structure and change that. This is a case of: "Oh, I have a problem. I'll use a regular expressions to fix it.". Now you have two problems.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing structured data with regex is almost always going to result in unreliable behaviors.

Instead, you can create a function that traverses sub-dicts recursively with a flag that indicates whether the current key is among the desired keys so that values would be replaced accordingly:

```
def remove_whitespace(data, keys, replace=False):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for key, value in data.items():
            data[key] = remove_whitespace(value, keys, key in keys)
    elif replace:
        data = data.replace(' ', '')
    return data
```

so that:

```
import json

data = '{"main":{"sem":"segon semestre","year":"2021","AUT":"admin  ","RES":"manel , admin ,lectura ","SUP":"kiloton  ","COR":"","fitx":"continguts"}}'
keys = ['AUT', 'RES', 'SUP', 'COR']
print(json.dumps(remove_whitespace(json.loads(data), keys)))
```

outputs:

```
{"main": {"sem": "segon semestre", "year": "2021", "AUT": "admin", "RES": "manel,admin,lectura", "SUP": "kiloton", "COR": "", "fitx": "continguts"}}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/Br4rBw

Answer (score 0):

Use the *json.loads* function to convert your JSON string into a Python dictionary.

Then just iterate over the relevant keys and adjust their values appropriately

```
from json import loads, dumps

JS = """{"main":{"sem":"segon semestre","year":"2021","AUT":"admin  ","RES":"manel , admin ,lectura ","SUP":"kiloton  ","COR":"   ","fitx":"continguts"}}"""

m = (d := loads(JS))["main"]

for key in "AUT", "RES", "SUP", "COR":
    m[key] = m[key].replace(" ", "")

print(dumps(d, indent=2))
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "main": {
    "sem": "segon semestre",
    "year": "2021",
    "AUT": "admin",
    "RES": "manel,admin,lectura",
    "SUP": "kiloton",
    "COR": "",
    "fitx": "continguts"
  }
}
```

**Note:**

The question seems to be asking for a recursive solution but I can't figure out why that would be necessary